# Change number locale format in CSV text (swap dot with comma in numbers)

Tags: ruby, regex, sed, formatting, number-formatting

I have a text file with comma delimited fields. The numeric field values are double quoted and formatted in [Italian locale](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) like `"4.294.967.295,000"`. Here are sample data from the text file:

```
Saldo contabile:,"1.123.456,89"
Saldo disponibile:,"1.123.456,89"

18/03/2014,16/03/2014,"-22,00","-23.122,00",EUR,AUT,-,43,PDPOT,"PAGOBANCOMAT            16/03/14,ORE 11:17,TESS.800999999                 FARMACIA XXXYYY DR.ZZZ",-
```

1

I want to change the format into the US-English locale like `"4,294,967,295.00"` by swapping `","` with `"."`, preferably by using sed, or vim, or Ruby. Swapping dot and comma is not a solution because comma is also used as the as the delimiter between fields.

So far [I was able to match fields](http://rubular.com/r/Md48bJhOlM) in which it is necessary to make the replacement:
[image: sample regexp to match numeric fields]

How can I swap points and commas only within numeric fields?

Comment: Is your example correct? It starts with `"PAGOBANCOMAT ` but there is no ending `"` -

Comment: Sorry,you are right. Just edited actually the value for that field is: "PAGOBANCOMAT            16/03/14,ORE 11:17,TESS.800999999                 FARMACIA XXXYYY DR.ZZZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a language with a real CSV parser. So ruby, not awk:

```
echo 'Saldo contabile:,"1.123.456,89"
Saldo disponibile:,"1.123.456,89"'|
ruby -rcsv -ne '
  row = CSV.parse_line($_)
  row.each {|elem| elem.tr!(",.",".,") if elem.match(/^-?[0-9,.]+$/)} 
  puts CSV.generate_line(row)
'
```

```
Saldo contabile:,"1,123,456.89"
Saldo disponibile:,"1,123,456.89"
```

Ruby has a `-i` option that works like `sed -i` to update the file inplace, if you need that.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the answer you expect: You could make two steps one after the other.

In Ruby: `s.gsub('.','').gsub(',','.')`

[This action could be integrated in a CSV-parser.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-converter)

Example:

```
require 'csv'
data = <<data
Saldo contabile:,"1.123.456,89"
Saldo disponibile:,"1.123.456,89"
Saldo disponibile:,"-1.123.456,89"
data
CSV::Converters[:num_it] = ->(s) {(s =~ /[-\d\.,]+/) ? (s.gsub('.','').gsub(',','.').to_f) : s}
#Alternative version with String#tr
#CSV::Converters[:num_it] = ->(s) {(s =~ /[-\d\.,]+/) ? (s.tr('.,', '_.').to_f) : s}
csv = CSV(data, :headers => false, :col_sep => ',',
                #~ :converters => :all
                :converters => [
                    *CSV::Converters.keys,
                    :num_it
                ]
            )
csv.each do |row|
  #~ p row
  print row[0];print " %.2f\n" % row[1]
end
```

Result:

```
Saldo contabile: 1123456.89
Saldo disponibile: 1123456.89
Saldo disponibile: -1123456.89
```

---

Beside the version with two `sub`, you could also try one [`String#gsub` with the hash or block-version](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub):

```
s = "1.123.456,89"
p s.gsub(/[\.,]/, {'.' => ',', ',' => '.'}) #-> "1,123,456.89"
p s.gsub(/[\.,]/){|hit| hit == '.' ?  ',' : '.'} #-> "1,123,456.89"
```

Comment: +1 for the directions to CSV. thanks this helps a lot.